# iOS custom font glyph spacing problem

Tags: iphone, fonts

I've added a custom TTF font to my iOS universal app (put .ttf file into resources, add the font file name to the info.plist as indicated on other threads here and the Apple dev forum).

I see the font applied to the UILabel's where I set it to, but there's a spacing problem: it appears as if there is a space character typed in between each glyph.   When I install the same .ttf file on my mac and use it in an app like TextEdit, there is no such spacing issue.

Any ideas?  Could this be a .ttf problem?   What parameter would I adjust?   Can anyone recommend a TTF editor for the mac?

Or is this a iOS TTF issue perhaps?   I really hope I don't have to delve into CoreText and subclass UILabel in order to get this to work (but if I do, any code samples would be appreciated).

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was just a widely-spaced font.